# How to use an already existing wallet on the network?

Tags: transactions, wallet, python, solana.py

I am trying to transfer some funds using my private key in Python. Here's the code but I don't know how I can use my existing phantom wallet's secret key to make the transaction. Here's the code, can anyone explain?

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer

LAMPORT_PER_SOL = 1000000000

client: Client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

sender = Keypair.from_secret_key(<private key here>)
receiver = PublicKey()
#print(sender.public_key)
#print(sender.secret_key)
lamp = client.get_balance(pubkey= sender.public_key)['result']['value']

transaction = Transaction()
transaction.add(
  transfer(
    TransferParams(
      from_pubkey= sender.public_key,
      to_pubkey= receiver, 
      lamports= lamp/10
    )
  )
)
#transaction.add_signature(sender.sign(transaction.serialize()))
client.send_transaction(transaction, sender)
```

Comment: put your wallet's private key as the `from_secret_key` parameter. you may need to add `.encode()` after the string. also, make sure to put a public key in the receiver area or it will send your Solana to a new wallet. besides that, you should be good to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step 1 – Export your private key from your wallet

Phantom lets you export your private key from this menu.

[image: The ‘export private key’ button in the Phantom wallet]

Click ‘Export private key’ and save the string that results somewhere safe.

**NOTE**: Anyone who holds this key has complete control of your wallet and can drain all of the assets from it. Take great care not to leak it to the public.

## Step 2 – Materialize a keypair using the exported material

```
import bs58 from 'bs58';
import {Keypair} from '@solana/web3.js';

// The string you exported from Phantom.
const privateKeyBase58Encoded = '...';

// Decode that string to a byte array.
const privateKeyBytes = bs58.decode(privateKeyBase58Encoded);

// Materialize a `Keypair` using that private key.
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKeyBytes);
```

## Step 3 – Use that keypair to sign transactions as you normally would

Here's an example transaction you can use to test your imported keypair. It will execute a transaction and write the string ‘Hello world’ to the transaction's log.

```
const ix = new TransactionInstruction({
  keys: [
    {
      pubkey: keypair.publicKey,
      isSigner: true,
      isWritable: true,
    },
  ],
  programId: new PublicKey("MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr"),
  data: Buffer.from("Hello world", "utf8"),
});
const transaction = new Transaction({
  feePayer: keypair.publicKey,
  ...(await connection.getLatestBlockhash()),
}).add(ix);
const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [keypair]);
console.log(signature);
```

Comment: This example uses JavaScript, but the principles will apply equally to Python. Decode the exported key using a base58-string-to-python-bytes conversion, then import it using `Keypair.from_secret_key()`.